# how to handle a dropdown visibility manually instead of Vuetify controls this

Tags: vue.js, drop-down-menu, vuetify.js

I have created a dropdown menu in Vuetify which looks like this:

```
<v-menu offset-y>
                <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                    <v-btn text v-on="on">
                        Details
                    </v-btn>
                </template>
                <v-list>
                    <v-list-item>
                        <v-form ref="form">
                            <v-radio-group v-model="metrics" required>
                                <v-radio
                                    label="ABC"
                                    value="abc"
                                ></v-radio>
                                <v-radio label="XYZ" value="xyz"></v-radio>
                            </v-radio-group>
                            <v-divider></v-divider>
                            <v-radio-group v-model="order" required>
                                <v-radio
                                    label="Higher"
                                    value="higher"
                                ></v-radio>
                                <v-radio
                                    label="Lower"
                                    value="lower"
                                ></v-radio>
                            </v-radio-group>
                            <v-divider></v-divider>
                            <v-btn
                                @click="
                                    sortTableData(
                                        metrics,
                                        order,
                                        $props.tableItems
                                    )
                                "
                            >
                                Apply
                            </v-btn>
                        </v-form>
                    </v-list-item>
                </v-list>
            </v-menu>
```

- when I click the Dropdown and select for eg:Installs, the menu
  closes..
- I have to click the Dropdown again to choose higher/lower..
  and the menu closes again..
- And again I have to click the Dropdown to Click "Apply" button.

Is there Any way I can hold this menu until I click "**Apply**"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the idea here is to manually handle the dropdown visibility instead of letting Vuetify controls this.

To do so, you need to:

- add a `:close-on-content-click="false"` on your `<v-menu>` ([doc](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus/#api))
- add a `v-model` directive binded to a "data" boolean value (ex: `v-model="isDropdownDisplayed"`), initialized to `false` (closed dropdown at load)

*The first prop tells Vuetify to **not** close the dropdown when clicking on content (only an outside click will do it), while the second prop is linking the dropdown visilibity to your custom data boolean value.*

As your "data" boolean value is initialized to `false` (closed dropdown) and is automatically updated to `true` via the `v-model` when opening the dropdown, the left thing to do is to pass this value to `false` on your `sortTableData` method.

Assuming you're using [SFC](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) (but the approach is the same for pure JS components):

**Template**

```
<v-menu offset-y :close-on-content-click="false" v-model="isDropdownDisplayed">
  ...
</v-menu>
```

**Script**

```
{
  name: 'MyComponent',
  data: function () {
    return {
      isDropdownDisplayed: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sortTableData: function (/* args */) {
      // ...
      this.isDropdownDisplayed = false
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```